# How to get request query parameters in interceptor

Tags: nestjs, interceptor

I am developing a Nest.js project.

I have a interceptor which simply logs request parameters:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyRequestInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private logger: MyLogger) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<string> {
    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = http.getRequest();
    const params = request.params;

    // output is {}, no parameters showing
    this.logger.info(JSON.stringify(params)); 

    return next.handle()
  }
}
```

When I send request `GET http://localhost:9001/data?foo=1,2`, I expect to see log for `foo=1,2` but I see empty object `{}`.  So, where am I wrong? How to access query parameters of request in Nest.js interceptor?

Answer (score -1):

Try request.query

```
@Injectable()
    export class MyRequestInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
     
    
         constructor(private logger: MyLogger) {}
        
          intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<string> {
            const http = context.switchToHttp();
            const request = http.getRequest();
            const query = request.query;
        
      
            this.logger.info(JSON.stringify(query)); 
        
            return next.handle()
          }
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

example log interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class LogRequestInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
  ) { }

  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = http.getRequest();
    const id = v4();

    const { params, query, body, headers, user } = request;
    const { url, method } = request.raw;

    console.log('___________________________________________________________________________');
    console.log('url : ', url);
    console.log('method : ', method);
    console.log('params : ', params);
    console.log('query : ', query);
    console.log('body : ', body);
    console.log('headers : ', headers);
    console.log('id : ', id);

    // const message = { id, type: 'request', method, url, params, query, body, headers, user: (user || {}) };
    // this.logger.log(message);

    return next.handle()
      .pipe(tap(data => {
      }),
        catchError(err => {
          const { message: error, status, stack } = err;
          const errorMessage = {
            id, type: 'error', method, url, params, query, body, headers,
            user: (user || {})._id, data: { error, status, stack },
          };
          console.log('err', err);
          return throwError(err);
        }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).